# How can I remap keyboard keys?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am looking for general instructions on remapping keys.

Can someone tell me how to remap <kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> to <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> button?

I have looked through every thread here and none of the suggestions worked.

I am using a Swedish keyboard setup and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried using the Search function selecting the "votes" tab/button to filter results at AskUbuntu? The link at end of this comment may help you understand Argusvisions's answer and i will post one to in order to try and help. Here is one answer from search results when searching for "rempap key" using the advice just given - http://askubuntu.com/a/24930/102029

Answer (score 81):

This answer has been mostly made up using the information from the first three steps of this [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24930)  and this Ubuntu Forums [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7675138&postcount=2) to which it links/refers to. This [other Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94507) was very helpful to.  So all credit to NES, llazarte, bodhi.zazen and Argusvision.

To simply swap two keys functions:
From Terminal run `xev` and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> which would give something like

[image: Terminal window showing F9 KeyPress event]

Doing the same for <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> did not give any output in `xev` for me (or I could not find the "KeyPress event") so I used Argusvision's advice for using the Custom Shortcuts in All Settings but doing so in order to disable <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> as screenshot button by reassigning as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> then tried pressing again which gave me keycode 107 for <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> in `xev` like so

[image: Terminal window showing PrtSc KeyPress event]

Repeating the process for all four keys gave me

- <kbd>F9</kbd> = keycode 75
- <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> = keycode 107, action Print
- <kbd>F10</kbd> = keycode 76
- <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> = keycode 127, action Pause

To change a keys function we need to know the keycode of the NEW key being pressed and the "action" of the OLD or existing key for that function.

Now that we have the key codes for identifying the keys we now make the system do what we want by using `xmodmap` and as we know <kbd>F9</kbd> has "keycode 75" and <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> has the action of "Print" all we need to do is

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Print"
```

to make the <kbd>F9</kbd> key behave as if the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key has been pressed. i.e. the keycode stays the same but pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key will have different results.

Using `xev` with <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> also gave

[image: Terminal window showing Scroll Lock KeyPress event]

which confirms the "action" for the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key is "Pause" so for making the <kbd>F10</kbd> act as <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> trying

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 76 = Pause"
```

should give the desired results.

That is until you log out or shutdown etc so what we have to do after confirming the commands

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Print"
xmodmap -e "keycode 76 = Pause"
```

do give the desired results is sort out <kbd>SysRec</kbd> which is modified <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and swap over the other buttons so we do not have multiple instances of same key action .  Adding

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 107 mod1 = F9 Sys_Req"
```

should swap <kbd>F9</kbd> to where <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> was keeping the modified <kbd>SysReq</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>) again we can use `xev` to help verify this.

Swapping the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> buttons is easier

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 127 = F10"
```

After making sure that when running

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Print"
xmodmap -e "keycode 107 mod1 = F9 Sys_Req"
xmodmap -e "keycode 76 = Pause"
xmodmap -e "keycode 127 = F10"
```

does indeed do what is intended all that is left to do is get this happening at startup time. To do this run

```
xmodmap -pke|egrep  -e '(F9|Print)'
```

which gave me

[image: some more text]

we are only interested in the keycodes 75 and 107. Do the same for

```
xmodmap -pke|egrep  -e '(F10|Pause)'
```

which gave me

[image: even more text]

and we are only interested in the keycodes 76 and 127.

Create a new text document with your favourite text editor copy and paste the relevant information

```
keycode  75 = Print NoSymbol Print
keycode 107 = F9 Sys_Req F9 Sys_Req
keycode  76 = Pause NoSymbol Pause
keycode 127 = F10 NoSymbol F10
```

naming the file as `.Xmodmap` and saving it in your Home directory would allow you to run the changes simply by logging on after rebooting.

Comment: This worked fine for the current session, but it seems that Ubuntu 16.04 does not read .Xmodmap on reboot.

Comment: Thanks. I got xmodmap mess up and appreciate if you could help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026246/why-doesnt-my-substitution-of-the-super-key-for-the-alt-l-key-not-work-in-all-t

Comment: My normal DownArrow key seems broken - with your step by step tutorial I remapped it to the NumPad DownArrow key and it works fine - thanks and +1 !

Answer (score 35):

For newer  versions of Ubuntu, Xmodmap works but after you reboot, you lose your keymappings! Instead what I did was to edit the xbd file (**/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc**).

In this case you would add the following entries:

```
key <FK09> { [Print] };
key <FK10> { [Scroll_Lock] };
```

Then clear the xkb settings cache:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

After a reboot your keys are mapped corectly.

Comment: This post has a slightly "cleaner" xkb solution that doesn't rely on altering system-wide mappings: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65600/111905

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 16.04, unlike the creation of a .Xmodmap file which is ignored. And it works for all users. Still looking at how to make my changes also work in a Console without X.

Comment: This works but as a note, I was not able to have two keys mapped to the same key code. For example I was not able to get rid of the caps-lock key and make it a ctrl key. I had to make the ctrl key a caps-lock and then I could make the caps-lock, ctrl.

Comment: One doesn't need to reboot after that.
Simply use setxkbmap fr or setxkbmap gb intl or setxkbmap us intl or setxkbmap whatever_fits_your_keymap and you're good to go.

Answer (score 8):

Go to `System Settings > keyboard > Custom Shortcuts`. Here you can assign a command to any key or set of keys. Click the add (+) button. In the window that pops up, Name = `Print Screen` ; Command = `gnome-screenshot`. After you've created it, click on the line to the right of the name where it says "Disabled". That should change it to "New Accelorator" Just press F9.

Still looking for scroll lock.

> > After a little looking, I found an answer for scroll lock. I got started on this answer from what I found [here.](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=49023)
> >     You should be able to apply it to any set of keys using `xmodmap` from the terminal.
> >     Edit: You can also read more about Xmodmap [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Take a look at the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep F10`.
Mine is:

```
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
```

This means my <kbd>F10</kbd> key is `keycode 76`.
Yours maybe different since you are using a different layout.

So **I** should be able to assign scroll lock to <kbd>F10</kbd> with the following command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 76 = Scroll_Lock"
```

You will need to insert the "keycode" you found for **your** F10 key.

You could also look through `man xmodmap` and `xmodmap --help` for additional options.

For example, `xmodmap -pke` lists your keymap table as expressions. That way you can locate the expressions assigned to other keys as well.