# How to disable caps lock on boot

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lock-screen, capslock

Is there a way to disable the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> at boot, so it won't bother me when logging in?

Laptop: old Multicom Xishan W530E bought at http://multicom.no.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.

My latop has a problem with the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button. It keeps toggling on/off. It seems like it's a hardware issue, as I experience the same problem on Windows and other distros.

For some reason, the problem does not occur at the [disk unlocking screen](http://imacify.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Ubuntu-FDD-lock-Screen.jpeg) (?) before the login screen appears.

I've disabled the key with gnome-tweak-tool, and have tried most other fixes I could google up.

My main problem now is how these fixes only seems to work after I've logged into a user account. Writing my password on the log in screen is still at the mercy of the dreadful <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

The laptops BIOS settings doesn't have options for the keyboard, as far as I can see.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Hardware problem -> hardware solution... what about a cutter? ;-) (joking, but now fully --- I would really try to remove the key and cut the connection. I never understood the reason to be of the CapsLock key, anyway, if not to be remapped to Compose.).

Comment: Have you tried any keyboard remapping?  For instance check out this [answer]:(http://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys#296437)

Comment: @dazzle: I've tried remapping, and outright disabling caps lock. It works, but doesn't take effect until I've logged in. I still experience problems at the log in screen.

Comment: @Rmano: I'd rather try a software fix first, if possible. =] Worst case scenario, it's reversible.