# Swapping Caps Lock and Ctrl PROBLEM

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-layout, emacs, capslock

I have tried a few different ways to remap ctrl and caps lock and none of them seem to be working. I am running Ubuntu on a Mac through VirtualBox. The two methods I have tried are using

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

and altering the file

```
/etc/default/keyboard
```

by adding

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Neither of these options successfully make caps lock function as a ctrl key. What is really frustrating is that it DOES effectively change the control key to a caps lock key, however, this renders emacs pretty much useless and I can't even do basic commands.

Has anyone had this problem? Or know a work around? (I know that I can swap the keys on my mac itself, but I would like to only have them swapped inside the ubuntu environment.)

Thank you!

Comment: follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys