# Remap footpedal in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, remapping

I own a basic *footpedal with two buttons*, which I would like to set up to mimic `Control` and `Super`.

I've used `xmodmap` and `xev` before, as suggested [in this answer here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

But it turns out that the buttons of the footpedal are mapped to `a` and `c` at the moment and the system can't distinguish between the input from the pedal and the keyboard. So when I remap `a` to `Control`, it also remaps my keyboard. (I work on a Laptop with an external keyboard attached)

Below you can find the output of `xev` both for the external keyboard and from the footpedal. *Any Ideas? :)*

---

**Keyboard *a***

`KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xd8, subw 0x0, time 2976167, (-463,316), root:(561,368),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xd8, subw 0x0, time 2976232, (-463,316), root:(561,368),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

**Footpedal *a***

`KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xd8, subw 0x0, time 3114112, (-172,78), root:(852,130),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xd8, subw 0x0, time 3114408, (-172,78), root:(852,130),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this issue. I haven't been able configure my footpedal at all on 14.04.