# Mouse keys wont work after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, button

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and now the two buttons under my touch pad do not work correctly. The Left click works as the Right click and the right click does nothing. How do I reassign these keys?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out...

[How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

For your answer.

Comment: I looked into that and it tried it out, im getting "keypress Event"s and "keyrelease Event"s for every button but my Left and right Clicks.  There not giving me a keycode.

Comment: Is this happening only for a browser?

Comment: No, I would just like to get the functionality of my left and right mouse buttons, they are not working.  Left click brings up the right click menus and right click does nothing.

Comment: It does it no matter what I'm doing

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, it seems like they send an, "Event" but it does not work, try reinstalling your keyboard.