# Period has become a comma after update

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with a numpad on the right side. My setup for several years has been the English (US) keyboard set as my primary (or first)  input source and Portuguese (Brazil) as my second. I switch back and forth between the two input sources with no problem. However a recent update (few months ago) has changed the period key on the numberpad to a comma while English is set as the current input source. No other keys seem to be altered. If I remove the Portuguese input source completely the period button functions normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the Gnome Tweak Tool installed. There is an option under Typing>"Numeric keypad delete key behaviour" that was set to disabled. I changed that to "Four-level key with dot" which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While not the most ideal solution, you could simply [remap the <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/296437/606758). If it only happens when you're using a specific layout, it might be handy to make a shortcut that would allow you to turn the mapping on and off.