# Down Arrow Key is not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, remapping

My Down Arrow Key in the keyboard is not working. Is there any way to map its functionality into another key in Ubuntu. How can I solve this problem without replacing my Keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has an Accessibility suite called *Universal Access*, of which there are keyboard controls.  Unfortunately, no custom mapping tools.

Another tool I found was *Onboard* which presents a keyboard onto your screen.  If you have a big screen, this may be the fastest solution.

Third, there may be some possibility with Keyboard tool by creating a Custom Shortcut.  Reading over the options, it does not appear there is an actual key remapping mechanism but something to explore.

Best solution was discovered on StackExchange.

Checkout this thread.  There is a command which you can use to redefine keys called **xmodmap.**

[How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

Hope this helps.