# Enable AltGr in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard

How do I set the 'Alternate Characters Key' to 'Enabled' in Xubuntu?

As far as I can tell, the right alt key does nothing special in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I’m looking for an easy way to type special characters like;  ¢ © ”“  without hand-typing unicode.  What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is add a keyboard layout that has usage of the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (Right Alt) key.

I'm writing this on XUbuntu 16.04 LTS with Serbian (Latin) keyboard layout, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> works like a charm right out of the box. For example, I'm able to type `@\|€`, etc without an issue.

If you need help adding keyboard layouts try searching the net, or look at [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/).

You can check the keycode that your <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key returns by running `xev` command in the terminal. Then, press your <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, which should return (in the second row) something like:

```
keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift)
```

Comment: xev returns something very different from that:
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x1f6, subw 0x0, time 253692245, (68,93), root:(495,612),
    state 0x18, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: This seams to be the default key mapping for right alt (Alt_R). Installing a keyboard layout that uses the AltGr key instead should have changed that mapping. What keyboard mapping you use ?

You can change the key mapping manually. Perhaps instructions from this article may help you achieve that:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys#296437