# My super key is disabled. How to enable it?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcut-keys

Today somehow my <kbd>Super</kbd> key is disabled. I can't use it, neither the laptop keyboard nor external keyboard. When I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, it does not send the Super key signal to ubuntu (18.04 LTS). Somehow it changed.

I checked the <kbd>Super</kbd> key by `xev` command. Here is the output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
root 0x176, subw 0x0, time 4735544, (559,365), root:(661,519),
state 0x2010, keycode 133 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I have some key binding with <kbd>Super</kbd> key. I use keyboard shortcut for changing writing language, opening dash, changing window/application etc.

Please tell me how to enable the key.

**Update:**

The problem seems to occur after every shutdown. There might be an application which is overriding the key. Instead of running the command every time, I have figured out another simple way. See the updated answer.

Comment: Requesting a moderator/Admin to close this question.

Comment: nobody has to "close" your question, self-answering your question is absolutely fine (and encouraged) here. To indicate that you already have a solution and no longer looking for a solution, you may [may "accept" your answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it). But to accept your own answer you'll have to wait for 2 days (since the question was posted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked into [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys#296437) and ran

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Super_L"
```

which solved my problem.

**Update:**

The problem seems to occur after every restart (shutdown). I couldn't figure out why this happens. To prevent this, I added the following command in startup application:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Super_L"
```

Apparently, this is the only known solution to me.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @TRiG, Sorry, Askubuntu won't let me accept it before two days. I'll do it later.

Answer (score 1):

For my case I was using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and <kbd>12</kbd> on HP Victus. But I clicked on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> which locks the <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key since it was a gaming laptop which has such features enabled, i.e. you can lock the <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key to avoid accidental clicks on it. Clicking <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> unlocked it.