# No Alt Key on my keyboard

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

My Lenovo ThinkPad does not have an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I use Ubuntu 18.04.1. Can I get advice on how to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on CLI? For example if I need ever to restart the gnome shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: you could possibly map another key to alt, per this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your best bet would be to map an unused/rarely used key on your keyboard to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key per this tutorial:

[How do I remap keyboard keys for Ubuntu](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/blog/remap-keyboard-keys-for-ubuntu/)

And possibly check out this answer:

[How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)