# Ctrl and/or Fn is always locked/pressed

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I log into Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP Envy13 I can't input anything from my keyboard because Ctrl and/or Fn key is always pressed(they aren't actually). The problem I have is particular because I can input my password in the login screen without any problem, but when I log into my desktop it becomes impossible to input anything and that is why I can't make any try with the terminal, I can work only with the mouse.

I have tried to invoke the on-screen keyboard in the universal access settings but it doesn't work as well.

I have also tried to enter in terminal mode before booting but the problem persists.

Did anyone experience something like that? Does the fact keyboard works fine in login screen suggests something to you?

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: just for clarifying, you got a terminal from grub or from the system recovery ?
And anyway, in these terminal you had the same issue but on the login screen it works fine ? That wouldn't mean anything to me.

Comment: Now what would be understandable is that your x-session that probably comes through gdm3 and which brings the desktop, had a bug or is misconfigured because the login screen is before the session. But once again if you are having an issue with the keyboard on a standard terminal (and not an emulator), I'm quite lost. Try pressing `ctrl+alt+f5` when it's launched and see if it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Yvain comments, I have solved the issue.

While being in the login screen, I have pressed Ctrl+Alt+F5 that let me access to a terminal. In this terminal the keyboard worked fine and I could remap keys that weren't functioning properly.

In order to remap keys I have used the second answer that you can find in this thread 
[How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

Hope it can help.